# Menu and sub menu display inline

Tags: php, html, menu

I have a Menu which is come from the database, i.e dynamic menu. It is look like below.

[image: Menu]

Menu item "ALL" has Ecommerce, CMS, Web Design, Logo Design, Others sub menus.
While Ecommerce has X-Cart, Magento & Open Cart as sub menus.

Now, look below image.

[image: Sub Menu]

While clicking on Ecommerce Menu item the other main menu item disappears & Ecommerce's sub menu items displays instead. Same as for CMS menu item. But, If Any main menu item don`t have sub menu than the Main Menu displays as it is. Just like below image.

[image: Not Have Sub Menu]

How can I achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is My Tried code.....

```
<ul class="unstyled inline">
                <li><a href="all-portfolio" class="all selected">All</a></li>
                <?php
                    $sql_menu = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = '".$tempArray['id']."' ORDER BY `order`";
                    $result_menu = mysql_query($sql_menu);
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_menu);

                    if($num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        while($menu_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_menu))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>portfolio/<?php echo $menu_row["slug"];portfolio ?>" class="web"><?php echo $menu_row["name"]; ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql_ext = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = '".$tempArray['id']."'";
                        $sql_ext_result = mysql_query($sql_ext);
                        $sql_ext_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_ext_result);

                        $sql_menu = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = '".$sql_ext_row["parent_id"]."' ORDER BY `order`";
                        $result_menu = mysql_query($sql_menu);

                        while($menu_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_menu))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>portfolio/<?php echo $menu_row["slug"];portfolio ?>" class="web"><?php echo $menu_row["name"]; ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to achieve this? Also please include some code of your menu / where it's build

Comment: Build in core php. I have edited the question. Please see it!! @Epodax

Comment: So, just to see if I understand the issue, you want the main menu to remain visible when a item with a sub menu is selected?

Comment: Yes and If Main Menu Item does not have sub menu that Main Menu will be displayed. And if Mani Menu Item has sub menu that it`s children are display in the right side of it & It`s parent should be display left side of it. See images that I have uploaded. It will give you more CLEAR view. @Epodax